# The space that malloc() used to keep track of allocated size

Tags: c++

`malloc()` function will put some info in the 8 bytes (in 64bit system) before the returned point some info about the size of the buffer. But there is some difference which is large than what I expected.

```
char *p = (char*)malloc(0x12345678);
```

the 8 bytes before it shows the number 0x12346002

```
(gdb) x/32ubx p-8
0x7fffe56cf008: 0x02    0x60    0x34    0x12    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffe56cf010: 0x68    0x65    0x6c    0x6c    0x6f    0x20    0x77    0x6f
0x7fffe56cf018: 0x72    0x6c    0x64    0x0a    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffe56cf020: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

Wonder why there is such a big difference

Comment: Using a linked list to store what is being used and what is not

Comment: Try printing `((long*)p)[-1]`. But bear in mind there are no guarantees about any of this.

Comment: Contrary to your assertion, C++ does not actually specify what `malloc` puts in the memory before the one given by its return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `malloc()` function will put some info in the 8 bytes (in 64bit system) before the returned point some info about the size of the buffer.

Although this is a very common way of implementing memory management routines, it is not universal; for example, a library could keep a separate hash table to track allocation sizes. The standard allows libraries to choose their preferred method of implementation.

> the 8 bytes before it shows the number 0x12346002

Pretend for a moment that poking into the 8 bytes before the allocated address is not undefined behavior (while actually it is). The library is allowed to round numbers up as they see fit, in order to optimize potential `realloc`s. In this case, the library decided to allocate 2442 additional bytes in case you decide to `realloc` later.

> Wonder why there is such a big difference

While in absolute numbers 2442 is a lot, it is a tiny amount in relation to the overall size of the allocation.

Comment: It's not even just because of `realloc`, it is also a *huge* win against fragmentation when you free some pages again later.

Comment: Wish there is a way to instruct malloc() not to allocate extra space.

Comment: @codingFun No, you don't. But if you can guarantee you will free all such chunks together, you can write a pool allocator out of a single large chunk that you get from `malloc`.

Comment: @o11c seems one can't avoid reinventing the wheel.  Thanks.

Comment: @codingFun From your level of experience, I highly doubt that reinventing the wheel is *actually* what you want to do.